# Use a method from a C# DLL inside SSAS Measures

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ssas, mdx

I have a C# dll in which developers are going to implement some functionality

We want to use these functions within the Meaures calculation.

Is this possible to do?  Has anyone ever tried to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Define the `class` implementing the functions as `public`. Define the functions also as `public`. If `Measures` calculation is being done in a separate DLL\Project, just reference the DLL containing the functions. This should work.

Comment: Are you sure you talking about Analysis Services?

Comment: Yes, MDX can contain calls to external functions. It was possible back with SQL2000 and old skool DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use external asseblies in MDX (both managed and unmanaged however due to this risk and other considerations, COM assemblies were deprecated in SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services) You have to add this assembly to ssas project in BIDS:
[image: add assembly in BIDS]

and then to ssis server itself on server or database level:

[image: add assembly to ssas server]

Then you can use your methods using `AssemblyName.FullClassName.ProcedureName(Argument1, Argument2, ...)` syntax.

More info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175398.aspx